# Trying to use javascript in a forum post

Tags: jquery, datatables, forum

I'm making a post in a forum and I'd like to use a [dataTable](http://www.dataTables.net).  I've added in the following to the top of my post:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, when I go to add in the following, the `$` get turned into `&#36;` (when I view the source of the post after it's posted):

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#wcw').dataTable({"sPaginationType":"full_numbers"});});</script>
```

I'm not sure if the `$` is the problem as to why the table isn't being "transformed" or if it's because of trying to use the jquery scripts.  [Here's the page.](http://www.beckett.com/forums/announcement-7.html)

Comment: are you the forum developer, or just a user? if just a user, I don't think you can use javascript. if the developer, you are already using **PrototypeJs** you can't use `$`, and you have plenty of javascripts errors to deal first

Comment: Not a developer of the forum, but a moderator of the forum.  I was going to ask them, but didn't want to bother them with this when they're trying to get another site rolled out by this weekend.  Figured it's better and easier to try asking here.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most forums do not allow javascript in posts due to security reasons. Such attacks in userinput which is later shown on the page to public are called [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)-Attacks (cross-site scripting attacks). You can try to share the table on a site which is specialy made for this usecase and post a link to it in the forum.

**EDIT:**

I saw that `<script>`-tags are allowed on the site. You can then try to use jQuery in [noconflict-mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Try following:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict(); jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('#wcw').dataTable({"sPaginationType":"full_numbers"});});</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if they have XSS turned on.  I'm a moderator on the forum and I tested this before.  At that time, I had an `ENTER` after the `<script>` tag and it didn't insert it into the DB, but this time I tried a oneliner (like I do with my local styles on the forum) and it worked, so I figured there might be a way to get it to work.  Thanks.

Comment: updated my answer. Give it a try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hmmm, I think they've done something since to disable it.  Now when I put in the lines of script, they all come out right as text, unless that's just the specific forum I'm in.  I'll give this another try though.  Thanks.